# Reactjs does not order correctly with additional static component

Tags: reactjs

I have a initially empty list of components that the user can create. There is additionally always a "static" component so the user can always add one regardless of the status of the list.
However the order does not match: when I add one and then another the order is wrong.
I tried to force the parent component to re-render but ... it doesn't work. The problem I believe is with the "static component" but I don't know how to do that otherwise.
Here is a minimal example of my bug on https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-water-e47ly?file=/src/App.js

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a bug. Your code logic tells React to act like that.

After some changes in the logic, here's a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-water-d36ze?file=/src/App.js

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It does but I don't understand why my example why failing. The array "values" is in the right order, i.e. if I type "1", then "2" , then "3", the "values" array contains ["1","2","3"], however the child component don't get drawn in the right order, even though everything should be re-rendered. Why is that ?

Comment: Actually, your code is wrong for so many reasons:
- first, when the values state changes the last fixed item won't be re rendered, so it  will always have the value entered by the user
- second, you're not displaying the value in the ChildComponent so you are just creating an empty child component for each value which explains why you have as empty inputs as much the values. Can you accept the response if it does solve your issue.